# Transforming one word into another word by changing only one letter at a time

Tags: c, algorithm, graph

How would I approach this algorithmic problem?

> Given two words of equal length that are in a dictionary, write a
>   method to transform one word into another word by changing only one
>   letter at a time. The new word you get in each step must be in the
>   dictionary.

Example:

```
Input: DAMP, LIKE
Output: DAMP -> LAMP -> LIMP -> LIME -> LIKE
```

Comment: Edit distance? Is this homework?

Comment: This [wolfram blog post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/01/11/the-longest-word-ladder-puzzle-ever/) may help you.

Comment: As a side-note to the question: The Levenshtein or any other edit distance is made irrelevant by the requirement that each intermediate word must be in the dictionary. The edit distance is trivial here anyway because insertions and deletions are forbidden.

Comment: Its not a homework, actually my placement season is going on, so I prepare for that.

Comment: @thiton: OK, but an "editing distance" algorithm can help identify words in the dictionary that are one letter different.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: True, but identification of similar words is not the hard part in this exercise. The hard part is using only dictionary words as intermediates. The output path might be much longer than the Levenshtein distance of the inputs.

Comment: Do the intermediate words have to be of the same length as the original word? For example, COAT -> CROW: COAT -> COT -> COW -> CROW. In other words, can inserting or deleting a letter be considered a change of one letter?

Comment: @thiton: If you use an editing distance to get a one-off word from the dictionary, you've solved both problems simultaneously.

Comment: @erickson: It's a [Word Ladder.](http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/01/11/the-longest-word-ladder-puzzle-ever/)

Comment: If I remember correctly, this must be a [USACO](http://train.usaco.org/usacogate) problem statement, or alike

Comment: @RobertHarvey And, "Some word ladder puzzles allow you to add or remove letters..."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try thinking this problem in terms of [graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29): Consider all words in a dictionary as vertices, and insert an edge between each two vertices that differ by only one letter. The output is a well-known object in the graph, and you probably already know an algorithm to solve the problem.

**Spoiler**:

> The output is a path in the graph, and the question is solved by finding a path. A [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) (BFS) or [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) solve the problem elegantly.

Comment: It's highly likely that the OP doesn't know anything about nodes or graphs.  What is an "edge?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Thanks for the suggestion, linked to Wikipedia to define the basic concepts.

Comment: Sir, can you elaborate how will you make the graph out of the dictionary in a time efficient manner.

Comment: @devsda: Compute the edit distance between each two words, which is in O(n^2) time complexity, and insert an edge for each edit distance of 1.